# How to remove black/white area around my Tab Bar

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm very new to swift coding and I followed a tutorial for this Custom Tab Bar.

But when I implement it in my project, theres black/white (dark/light mode) spaces or areas around the actual tab bar. How do i remove this? I was hoping for the tab bar to just be floating on top of content as you scroll.

Heres my Custom Tab Bar view code:

```
import SwiftUI

enum Tab: String, CaseIterable {
    
    case house
    case person
    
}

struct CustomTabBar: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab: Tab
    private var fillImage: String {
        selectedTab.rawValue + ".fill"
    }
    
    private var tabColor: Color {
        switch selectedTab {
        case .house:
            return .blue
        case .person:
            return .indigo
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(Tab.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { tab in
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: selectedTab == tab ? fillImage : tab.rawValue)
                        .scaleEffect(selectedTab == tab ? 1.25 : 1.0)
                        .foregroundStyle(selectedTab == tab ? tabColor : .gray)
                        .font(.system(size: 22))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation(.easeIn(duration:0.1)) {
                                selectedTab = tab
                            }
                        }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .frame(width: nil, height: 60)
            .background(.thinMaterial)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .padding()
        }
        .background(Color.clear)
    }
}

#Preview {
    CustomTabBar(selectedTab: .constant(.house))
}
```

and heres my main view where I connected the icons to the two views if this is of any use:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = MainViewViewModel()
    @State private var selectedTab: Tab = .house
    
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if viewModel.isSignedIn, !viewModel.currentUserId.isEmpty {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    switch selectedTab {
                    case .house:
                        ToDoListView(userId: viewModel.currentUserId)
                    case .person:
                        ProfileView()
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    CustomTabBar(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
                }
            }
        } else {
            LoginView()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an image of my tab bar:

[image: Screenshot]

I tried to make the background of the VStack in the CustomTabBar transparent so the black/white area wouldnt show but it didnt work (unless i did it wrong).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where do those actors like MainViewViewModel, ToDoListView, ProfileView come from?  And why do you need to state them here?

Comment: In `CustomTabBar`, the top-level `HStack` has padding around it. This is nested in a `VStack` with clear background. **Try removing the padding.** You can then remove the `VStack` too, it will be redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine in my testings. So far I tried something like this and everything works as expected:

```
NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            List(1...100, id: \.self) { index in
                Text("\(index)")
            }
        }
    }
    .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
        CustomTabBar(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
    }
```

If you use overlay to display your tab bar you are basically making it floating on top of the content the overlay is applied to.
I would suggest replacing NavigationView with NavigationStack unless you have a specific reason for that. If the issue persist is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks for much! This worked perfectly. It seems like the .overlay was what I was missing.